# How to `JSON.parse` with jQuery? (to support old browsers?)

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

Is it possible to call the internal function in jQuery that does `JSON.parse`?

I want to support IE8 and IE9 but they don't have `JSON.parse` so I can't just call it in my code. I've to use an external library for JSON, but I already use jQuery.

My application receives data from an AJAX call but it's not quite JSON. I then modify data to turn it into JSON string, and then I need to parse it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) is not an "internal function in jQuery". It's just plain old JavaScript.

According to MDN:

[image]

As you can see, the `JSON#parse` method is implemented in IE8 and above.

> My application receives data from an AJAX call but it's not quite JSON.

It either is or it isn't JSON. If it *is*, then it needs to be formatted correctly or it won't transport, if your AJAX call specifies JSON as the expected `content-type`. If it isn't JSON, then you need to specify the correct `content-type` that is expected in the response and parse it thusly. There's no "almost" JSON. If there is the tiniest mistake in formatting, you'll never receive the data.

Comment: Thanks that works! My application receives string wrapped in HTML tags, which is almost JSON data. I then strip HTML and I'm left with a string that is valid JSON. I call `JSON.parse` and it's now valid js object. It has nothing to do with content-type in my case.

Comment: Almost JSON - I mean thing like `<b>{ "list" : "[1,2,3]"}</b>` - it almost JSON. If I stripe <b> and </b> I'm left with [1,2,3] which is JSON